# Are values of an object attributes, or are values themselves objects?

Tags: python, class, oop, object

For example, `a=5`, does it create an int object with a value 5 or is 5 an object itself?

Let us take an employee class. When we instantiate `e1=employee("Rakesh","Singh", 6000)` it creates an employee object `e1` with attributes `fname=Rakesh`, `lname= Singh` and `Pay=6000`.
But in the above case can we say `e1` is equivalent to 5 (as they both are instances of different classes) or is `e1` equivalent to an `int` object with value 5 ?

I am confused, is the value itself an object or is it an attribute?

Comment: I'm not sure where you're seeing a 5 anywhere in `e1=employee("Rakesh","Singh", 6000)`.

Answer (score 2):

Python is dynamically typed and variable names can be assigned to different data types later on in a program.

When it is declared that `a = 5`

1. An integer object of value 5 will be created (note that `int`'s and `str`'s in Python are immutable objects. You can't assign new value(s) to this objects. If you do, new objects are created (and not necessarily, existing objects of same value can be reused).
2. The 5 int object and the name `a` are bound.
3. Whereas `a` is only a reference/pointer that points to that object. The reference term is preferred  because you can't do things like pointer math, as in the C language. References are aliases to objects.

Hence, `5` is an int object of value `5` referred by the name/reference `a`.

Besides this, everything in Python is actually an object. Including functions, classes, exceptions and so on.

An object can have one or more attributes. And in Python every attribute is also an object.

Comment: so can we say that values themselves are objects or not? Is 5 an object itself or is it a value of the object(which can be interpreted in terms of object's attributes)

Comment: @ChyanitSingh We are just calling `5` an `int` object. Try also `a=int(5)`. It's the same as `a=5` but makes explicti that 5 is just a data parameter you send to the `int` object initialization. You cannot guess what 5 is from object's outside because that's an implementation detail that doesn't matter (internal representation, "private" to the `int` class)

Comment: In other words you can say that the object referred by `a` is an int object with the value 5. The "value" of the object can be a group of several attributes (all of them objects too) but not in the int case, that has a single value.